# UIImage Animation disables buttons when using UIViewController+Transitions

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I have project that is giving me some headache and i think its because i need to learn by doing stuff and therefore i miss out on some fundamental stuff in iOS so don't yell at me! :-).

I have a iOS iPad storyboard consisting of approx. 33-35 ViewControllers.
The concept is "the World" and you go down view by view till you hit the surface where i have a UIImage that is animated (25png at 1,7f duration).
Since presentModalView just overwrite the old view instead of pushing it up when the other view is coming in from the bottom i added the UIViewController+Transitions ( http://srooltheknife.blogspot.no/2012/03/custom-transition-animation-for-modal.html ) to also animate removal of the old view witch works perfect..
But, when i use this extra library whenever i use animations in a UIImageView all touch events seems to be disabled. I have tried the enableUserInteraction = YES on both the view, buttons, view but did not help.

Any Idea?

Here is the viewController that has the animation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Main world view loaded....");
    NSLog(@"Bounds = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
    //self.view.bounds = self.view.frame;
    NSLog(@"Bounds are now = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
    self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    NSLog(@"User interaction is enabled?= %i", self.view.userInteractionEnabled);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=1; i<=24; i++) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Untitled-%d", i] ofType:@"png"]]];
    }
    world.animationImages = images;
    world.animationDuration = 1.7;
    [world startAnimating];


    NSLog(@"Preparing audio");
    NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mainWorldSound" ofType:@"wav"]];
    NSError *audioError;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&audioError];
    if(audioError){
        NSLog(@"Error in audioplayer: %@", [audioError localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:NULL];
        player.numberOfLoops = -1;
        player.volume = 1.0;
        if([player isPlaying]){
            [player stop];
        }
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player play];
        NSLog(@"Playing with volume: %f", player.volume);
    }


    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

So before this view is loaded i have 5 view controller that is just text and pictures with swipe event to go down.. This is the code to load the new ViewController (above) and animate it in:

```
- (IBAction)goToMainWorld:(id)sender {
    [self doVolumeFade];
    ViewController *mainWorld = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainWorld"];
    [self presentModalViewController:mainWorld withPushDirection:kCATransitionFromBottom];

}
```

To make thing easier to see i'm adding a screenshot from my storyboard..
Here (I'm not allowed to post pictures yet): [enter link description here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/163/skjermbilde20120903kl11.jpg/)

I've also tried to modify the UIViewController+Transitions.m to use the navigationController
Default

```
[self presentModalViewController:modalView animate:NO];
```

To:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewcontroller:modal view animate:NO];
```

but if i do that it loads the first animated view controller fine, but all other is just the first view controller being re-animated if that make sense?

Sorry for my bad English!

If i need to provide more code please let me know! :-)..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. I've kind of figured it out myself and it seems like my technique of using views for each "view" was not suck a good idea..

I had never seen UIScrollView and figured it was worth to try and seems like its the solution for me.

MemoryVise its about the same, but i now get the transitions etc that Marketing wants.

Only issue now is to get the sound to fade in and out for each ScrollView page and also control the sound in the second UIScrollView at the bottom seems to give me some headache.

Thanks
Regards
Audun